# Detecting WebSockets with HAProxy in TCP mode

Tags: websocket, haproxy

If I want to do SSL passthrough on HAProxy, I understand that I need to do use tcp mode. If I also want to detect WebSockets (previously done with `acl is_websocket hdr(Upgrade) -i WebSocket`) is there a way to do this when HAProxy is in TCP mode? I've tried a few different things without any luck. Any suggestions welcomed!

Answer (score 1):

When doing SSL passthrough it is impossible to analyze the transferred data because the traffic is encrypted. Since the information about Websocket upgrade is only in the encrypted HTTP header detection is not possible.